# 5 V to 500 V converter PCB review

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, review

After spending about an hour researching, I opened EasyEDA for the first time to make a circuit. It is supposed to convert 5 V from a USB port into 500 V in order to power a neutron detection tube.

I'm not really sure about some parts of this, and I couldn't figure out how to use the built-in simulator.

The DC voltage first goes through an inverter, then a small transformer to get 50 V, then through a voltage multiplier to end up with 500 VAC. I then put it through a rectifier and get 500 VDC at a really low current. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Links to [circuit file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pA56vUX3S1sQDBMbAM0tGXGbyECCMXsk/view?usp=sharing) and [PCB file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bldWC0DZB8R2VOgQvoA7skmjQRQMI1nC/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why there is an A type USB connector on a device that takes in power? 500VAC rectified is 700VDC with no load.

Comment: Your D11-14 are superfluous. D10 charges C10, which is groundy, and that's your high voltage DC output. Does C12 need to be that big? 100 uF at 500 V is a LOT of energy, I'm sure your application could use less. C12 needs a discharge resistor across it, to drain it of energy after switch-off, for safety. A bulk capacitor at USB1 might be useful. Your schematic is horrible, the D1-10 C1-10 connections and ref des are illegible, though the PCB appears to be correctly wired in that area. Please draw your oscillator conventionally. A readable schematic is essential if you want help from others.

Comment: How accurate do you need the output to be? Did you simulate this? Your choice of grounds seems odd.

Comment: Is Q1 the right way round? Either polarity, or connections? Did you simulate or build this to test it?

Comment: You should maximise clearances between differing voltages. I'd expeçt some lightning effects in non ideal circumstances at present